# How return memorystream from Compact Framework 3.5 using WCF 3.5

Tags: wcf

From Video
 Luggage i need captue foto or video and return without saving
I would be grateful for any direction on this topic
if this is possible?

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to write to the stream from the service?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You're not doing very well. What is this camera? What do you mean, "return without saving"?

Comment: Are you using the WIA/TWAIN drivers or something different?

Comment: from flash memory without saving on HDD
2Bobb No do not use but thanks for the direction

Comment: Is this camera a CF 3.5 device? Is it running a program that you have written or are going to write?

Comment: @Alexandr: you should either clarify your question, or maybe get someone to translate for you. I have little or no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this and found that Compact Framework does not appear to support WCF.

Comment: stream on the server will be written in file. The source code can lay out only after 8 hours

Comment: My project works fine with this technology
More information server will be located on a standard pc
cf implemented on the client only problem in the transfer on stream

Comment: @Alexandr: I created a "Smart Device Project" in VS2008, and tried to add a Service Reference to it. The menu item does not appear, so I'm assuming that's not supported.

Comment: I hope you trying add web referens?
You are doing something that is not properly
You can read about wcf in cf3.5 in msdn

Comment: Returning to the theme of my post how to return stream from smartDevices except bynary array?

Comment: @Alexandr: yes, i tried a web reference, and it "worked". It allowed me to pass a byte array. Please post a link to where it says you can use WCF in CF3.5.

Comment: http://www.worksurf.org/cgi-bin/nph-proxy.cgi/000110A/http/msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397835.aspx

And this how to video if anyone needed

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc302399.aspx
http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/jimw/archive/2008/05/11/50892.aspx